# alert or log click function content

Tags: javascript, logging, onclick, click

The following code:

```
alert(document.getElementById("div").click());
```

runs the click function. But I want to alert or log the content of such a function. What have i to do instead?

Comment: Do you mean content of the element?

Comment: _I want to alert or log the content_  - What content?

Comment: Content of the function specified for click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` method is a DOM Level 2 method for `<input>` elements with type "button", "checkbox", "radio", "reset", or "submit" (see: [DOM-Level-2-HTML: click method](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361) and [HTMLElement.click() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)).

The `click` method (function) itself is implemented natively by the browser. It means that you **can** try to print its content with:

```
alert(document.getElementById("div").click);
```

(note no parentheses after `click`) but all you will get is:

```
function click() { [native code] }
```

which is probably not what you want.

Are you sure you don't want to get the source of click **event handlers** instead of a click **method**?

Answer (score 1):

To print out the content of the function, you have to execute:

`console.log(document.getElementById("div").click)`

Then go to the console of [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), where you will find a reference to the source code of logged function, or just the source, if it's native browser's implementation.

```
console.log(''.toLocaleLowerCase)
toLocaleLowerCase()                                                                VM222:2

console.log($);
e(e, e)                                                                            VM227:2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to actually alert the source code of the click function, yes?

Just remove the parentheses, which are what tells javascript to run the function rather than reference the function:

```
alert(document.getElementById("div").click);
```